# Which Operating Systems have Native File Event Notification Facility? Do all Windows versions have it?

Tags: java, file, notifications, operating-system, watchservice

I read that WatchService API in Java 7 requires a Native File Event Notification Facility or otherwise it will use polling. Which OS have this facility? Is there a version in Windows that does not have it?

Comment: The real question should be; which versions of Windows are supported by Java 7. http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/config-417990.html  The rest don't matter.

Comment: Yeah, you need Java 7 to run WatchService. But my question is not which OS versions can run it. My question is in which operating system will the watchservice use polling (those without a File Notification System)? Documentation says that if your OS does not have a File Notification System, and supports Java 7, you will be able to use the WatchService API, but the WatchService will use polling.

Comment: I don't know of any supported version of Windows which doesn't have a File Notification System. I have tested Windows 7+, I don't know about Vista.

Comment: Both answers were really helpful. Thank you Peter.